# Understanding IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I have a class that has a `DbConnection` variable. In the class constructor I assign a new `DbConnection` instance to it. Since it is an `IDisposable`, am I supposed to do something with it at my class's destructor (or somewhere else)?
I know that if using it it one piece of code I am supposed to wrap it in a `using` block, tough I am not sure why, but here I am assigning it once and using it for all calls to my class.

If it makes any difference, I am using C# 4.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Since it is an IDisposable, am I supposed to do something with it at my class's destructor (or somewhere else)?

No, typically you won't *have* a finalizer/destructor - they're [almost never needed in modern .NET](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=86c71425-57bc-4fcb-b34b-3262812f12cf).

However, your class *should* implement `IDisposable`, and dispose of the database connection there. That way you're basically passing on the responsibility for disposing to whoever creates an instance of your class.

Comment: Doesn't `Dispose` get called automatically when my class is destroyed?

Comment: No, it does not.  You must either manually call .Dispose() on it, or wrap it in a using statement (which will call .Dispose() on it when the block is exited).  In your case, you should use Jon's suggestion and make your class implement IDisposable, and then use one of the above-mentioned ways to dispose of it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

All classes that deal with non-managed resources implement `IDisposable`. This way you make sure that unmanaged resources are being released after their use by either `using() {}` or calling the `Dispose`-method.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
IDisposable Interface - Defines a method to release allocated resources.
```

Answer (score 0):

This article might be helpful - [Implementing a Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx)

Basically classes that implement `IDisposable` have dependencies on some resources that needs to be fried when not needed any more. In your case that's connection to database. It would be not wise to keep connection open all the time. If you are using it inside `using` block - it will dispose object at the end of the block (it is syntactic sugar for `try finally` construction). If you hold it as object field/property - best idea is for your class to also implement `IDisposable` and make sure that the user of your class disposes it correctly.

Side note - you can dispose your objects in finalizers, but that's highly not recommended for normal workflow, so please do not go that way.

Answer (score 0):

surrounding ur dbconnection with "using" code block automatically dispose'es any open connection

```
using(sqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(connectionstring)){
//rest of the code here
}
```